Apache httpd Cache Response 'MISS from myexample.com' Issue
I'm experiencing issues configuring Apache httpd cache. Currently, files are being created in the CacheRoot directory, but I consistently see "MISS from myexample.com" in the response headers.
In httpd.conf:
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
    CacheRoot "/var/cache/httpd/apache-web-cache"
    CacheEnable disk "/"
    CacheDirLevels 2
    CacheDirLength 1
    CacheDetailHeader on
    CacheHeader on
    CacheQuickHandler off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

In vhost configuration (vhost-myweb-example-le-ssl.conf):
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName myexample.com
ProxyRequests off
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

SSLEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myexample.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myexample.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myexample.com/chain.pem

ProxyPass / http://mysvrip:port/
ProxyPassReverse / http://mysvrip:port/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
<LocationMatch ".(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|woff|woff2|ttf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000, must-revalidate, no-transform"
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>

Despite improving speed after configuring caching, I'm still encountering the "MISS from myexample.com" issue. I've set permissions for CacheRoot to 777 with user and group apache:apache. Is there a solution to this issue? I found success with NGINX configuration, but Apache httpd is proving challenging. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.
enter image description here
